# node module supertest - post method not working

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, tdd, supertest

I have this test below to test a controller /post endpoint but when I run this test, it keeps complaining about missing fields. I am providing the correct data in `.send()` method but for some reason its not able to detect it and says that the `name` field is missing.

```
    describe("/POST a book", () => {
        it("should save a book", async () => {
            var book_data = { name: "book_title" };
            const res = await request(app).post("/books")
            .send(book_data)
            .expect(201)
            .end(function(err, res) {
              if (err) return done(err);
              done();
            });
        });
    });
```

routes.js

```
 app.post('/books', [bookController.create_a_book]);
```

bookController.js

```
exports.create_a_book = function (req, res) {
    BookModel.createBook(req.body).then(
        (book) => {
            res.status(200).send({id: book._id});
        }
    );
};
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? I didnt see anything different from the online posts about it.

Comment: Edit your post and provide the code under test

Comment: updated my post

Comment: @slideshowp2 any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean `name` field is missing? You can't get the `name` field from `req.body` in your controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an integration test for your case, maybe you forget add the `body-parser` middleware.

`server.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const bookController = require("./bookController");
const http = require("http");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post("/books", [bookController.create_a_book]);

const server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:3000");
});

module.exports = server;
```

`bookController.js`:

```js
const BookModel = require("./bookModel");

exports.create_a_book = function(req, res) {
  BookModel.createBook(req.body).then((book) => {
    console.log("book: ", book);
    res.status(200).send({ id: book._id });
  });
};
```

`bookModel.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  async createBook(data) {
    data._id = Math.random();
    return data;
  },
};
```

`server.integration.spec.js`:

```js
const request = require("supertest");
const { expect } = require("chai");
const app = require("./server");

describe("/POST a book", () => {
  after((done) => {
    app.close(done);
  });
  it("should save a book", (done) => {
    const book_data = { name: "book_title" };
    request(app)
      .post("/books")
      .send(book_data)
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        console.log(res.body);
        if (err) return done(err);
        expect(res.body).to.haveOwnProperty("id");
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Integration test result with coverage report:

```sh
HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:3000
  /POST a book
book:  { name: 'book_title', _id: 0.2510749824531193 }
{ id: 0.2510749824531193 }
    ✓ should save a book (497ms)


  1 passing (502ms)

----------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                        |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files                   |    96.88 |       50 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 bookController.js          |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 bookModel.js               |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 server.integration.spec.js |    92.86 |       50 |      100 |      100 |                18 |
 server.js                  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58924579